# Изменить расположение элемента на экране

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить расположение кнопки Яндекс чата на экране. Кнопка чата по умолчанию правый нижний угол, но у меня там другая кнопка, обратный звонок. Как можно расположить кнопку чата Яндекс в противоположном углу или поднять выше относительно нижней части экрана?

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
(function () {
    window['yandexChatWidgetCallback'] = function() {
        try {
            window.yandexChatWidget = new Ya.ChatWidget({
                guid: 'd8d6da02-0857-5960-9b04-78d64c466539',
                buttonText: '',
                title: 'Чат',
                theme: 'light',
                collapsedDesktop: 'never',
                collapsedTouch: 'never'
            });
        } catch(e) { }
    };
    var n = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
        s = document.createElement('script');
    s.async = true;
    s.charset = 'UTF-8';
    s.src = 'https://chat.s3.yandex.net/widget.js';
    n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n);
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let circle = document.querySelector('.p');

let scrollHeight = Math.max(
  document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
  document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
  document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
);
circle.style.marginLeft = 30 + 'px';
circle.style.marginTop = scrollHeight + 'px';
circle.style.marginBottom = 50 + 'px';

console.log(scrollHeight)
```

```css
.p{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="p"></div>
```

1. Вариант который пришел мне в голову на js
2. Вместо круга подставляете чат и играетесь с margin на js
3. Лучше будет на мой взгляд это сделать на css

Comment: С css не подходит, не работает. Только черный круг верхнем углу а сам чат как был на месте так и есть )))

Comment: А js примером ругаться на         let circle = document.querySelector('.p');